# Remove newline before first variable tag in Jinja2

Tags: python, markdown, jinja2

I'm making a Jinja2 template to format some text.

```
template = jinja2.Template("""+++\nTitle: {{ title }}\ntags:\n+++\n
##Summary:\n\n
##Quote:\n>{{ quote }}\n\n**Citekey**: {{citekey}}\n\n
**Reference**: {{ ref }}\n\n##Comments:""")
```

Output

```
+++
Title: 
Transmitting Pain and Itch Messages:
A Contemporary View of the Spinal Cord Circuits that Generate Gate Control
tags:
+++
```

What I want

```
+++
Title: Transmitting Pain and Itch Messages:A Contemporary View of the Spinal Cord Circuits that Generate Gate Control
tags:
+++
```

There is a `\n` being inserted between the preceding text and the `{{title}}` tag. I'm sure this is something about how Jinja2 handles that first variable tag, but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Are you sure that the variable `title` doesn't have `\n` itself?

Comment: wherever you fill your title:   `stripTitle = mytitle.strip("\r").strip("\n")`

Comment: @OmarEinea Wow. I'm feeling dumb. That seems to be the problem. There was a newline from the command line argument I gave. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickArtner Also a good idea. I'm sure it won't be the last time I make this mistake. I'll strip everything. Thanks!